# How to get data from linq

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-core

I am trying to get data from linq in asp.net core. I have a table with a Position with a FacultyID field, how do I get it from the Position table with an existing userid. My query

```
        var claimsIdentity = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
        var userId = claimsIdentity.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier)?.Value.ToString();
        var data = _context.Positions.Where(p => p.UserID.ToString() == userId).Select(x => x.FacultyID).???;
```

What can I add after the mark? to get the data. Thank you so much

Comment: use FirstOrDefault

Answer (score 0):

There are several things you can do. An example in your case would be:
var data = _context.Positions.Where(p => p.UserID.ToString() == userId).Select(x => x.FacultyID).FirstOrDefault();

If you expect more than 1 results, then you would do:
var data = _context.Positions.Where(p => p.UserID.ToString() == userId).Select(x => x.FacultyID).ToList();

Answer (score 0):

You have to be aware of the difference between a query and the result of a query.

The query does not represent the data itself, it represents the *potential to fetch some data*.

If you look closely to the LINQ methods, you will find there are two groups: the LINQ methods that return `IQueryable<...>` and the others.

The IQueryable methods don't execute the query. These functions are called lazy, they use deferred execution. You can find these terms in the remarks section of every LINQ method.

As long as you concatenate IQueryable LINQ methods, the query is not executed. It is not costly to concatenate LINQ methods in separate statements.

The query is executed as soon as you start enumerating the query. At its lowest level this is done using `GetEnumerator` and `MoveNext / Current`:

```
IQueryable<Customer> customers = ...; // Query not executed yet!

// execute the query and process the fetched data
using (IEnumerator<Customer> enumerator = customers.GetEnumerator())
{
    while(enumerator.MoveNext())
    {
        // there is a Customer, it is in property Current:
        Customer customer = enumerator.Current;
        this.ProcessFetchedCustomer(customer);
    }
}
```

This code, or something very similar is done when you use `foreach`, or one of the LINQ methods that don't return `IQueryable<...>`, like ToList, ToDictionary, FirstOrDefault, Sum, Any, ...

```
var data = dbContext.Positions
    .Where(p => p.UserID.ToString() == userId)
    .Select(x => x.FacultyID);
```

If you use your debugger, you will see that `data` is an `IQueryable<Position>`. You'll have to use one of the `other` LINQ methods to execute the query.

To get all Positions in the query:

```
List<Position> fetchedPositions result = data.ToList();
```

If you expect only one position:

```
Position fetchedPosition = data.FirstOrDefault();
```

If you want to know if there is any position at all:

```
if (positionAvailable = data.Any())
{
    ...
}
```

Be aware: if you use the `IQueryable`, the data will be fetched again from the DbContext. So if you want to do all three statements efficiently these, make sure you don't use the original data three times:

```
List<Position> fetchedPositions result = data.ToList();
Position firstPosition = fetchedPostion.FirstOrDefault();
if (firstPosition != null)
{
    ProcessPosition(firstPosition);
}
```